# FATAL EXCEPTION: main ; OOP ; RuntimeException in JAVA

Tags: java, android, oop, getter-setter

I started to learn code and java.The submitted project consists of a single .java file, titled ReportCard.java. And i dont want a layout.xml file. I want create just a class. I didnt understand where is my mistake. Thank you very much your help :)

```
package com.example.android.reportcard; public class ReportCard {

// variable initializations and 
// necessary setters and getter functions

private String setGrade(int math, int science, int socialStudies) {
    String grade;
    mSum = math + science + socialStudies;
    mPercentage = mSum / TOTAL;

    if (mPercentage >= 90.0) {
        grade = "A";
    } else if (mPercentage < 90.0 && mPercentage >= 80.0) {
        grade = "B";
    } else if (mPercentage < 80.0 && mPercentage >= 70.0) {
        grade = "C";
    } else if (mPercentage < 70.0 && mPercentage >= 60.0) {
        grade = "D";
    } else if (mPercentage < 60.0) {
        grade = "Fail";
    } else {
        grade = "error";
    }
    return grade;
}


/**
 * Create new report card object.
 *
 * @param schoolName
 * @param teacherName
 * @param year
 * @param studentName
 * @param mathGrade
 * @param scienceGrade
 * @param socialStudiesGrade
 */

public ReportCard(String schoolName, String teacherName, String year, String studentName,
                  int mathGrade, int scienceGrade, int socialStudiesGrade) {
    mSchoolName = schoolName;
    mTeacherName = teacherName;
    mYear = year;
    mStudentName = studentName;
    this.mMathGrade = mathGrade;
    this.mScienceGrade = scienceGrade;
    this.mSocialStudiesGrade = socialStudiesGrade;
}

public String toString() {
    return "School: " + getSchoolName() + '\n' +
            "Student Name: " + getStudentName() + '\n' +
            "Teacher Name: " + getTeacherName() + '\n' +
            "Year: " + getYear() + '\n' +
            "Math Grade: " + mMathGrade + '\n' +
            "Science Grade: " + mScienceGrade + '\n' +
            "Social Studies Grade: " + mSocialStudiesGrade + '\n' +
            "Grade: " + setGrade(mMathGrade, mScienceGrade, mSocialStudiesGrade);
    }
}
```

And the Error:

```
Process: com.example.android.reportcard, PID: 27731
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.reportcard/com.example.android.reportcard.ReportCard}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.android.reportcard.ReportCard> has no zero argument constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.android.reportcard.ReportCard> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: removed unwanted code form the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android application is not the same as a console application. An  Android application always requires a graphical entry point in the form of a Launching Activity, in order for the platform to know where to start executing code. Think of it as the `main` method in regular Java applications.

**From the [Android Activity Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):**

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost
>   all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes
>   care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with
>   setContentView(View).

In order to create a `ReportClass` object and use its declared fields and methods, you will need to declare your application's entry point. To do this, create a new class and call it `MyMainActivity`.

```
public class MyMainActivity extends Activity
{


}
```

**Again, paraphrasing from the [Android Activity Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):**

> The onCreate(Bundle) method will be implemented by almost all of the classes extending Activity. This method is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

The next step is to implement the onCreate method mentioned in the docs. Given that you are not going to interact with the user interface, you can simply call `setContentView()` using an empty layout. Don't pay attention to the Bundle argument, as it will only confuse you for now.

```
public class MyMainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.my_empty_layout);
    }
}
```

You should create the `my_empty_layout.xml` file in the `/res/layout` folder, and the you can leave the generated content as is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

The final thing you need to do is specify to the platform which Activity should be the entry point to your application. Even though you have only declared one, you will still need to specify it. This is done in the Android Manifest file, located at `/app/manifests`. There will already be `xml` content there, including an `<application>` `</application>` tag. Inside this element, add an activity child node (``` <activity>``</activity> ```) in which you specify the full path to your declared activity, as well as mark it as your applications entry point using an `intent-filter`. The activity node should then look something like this:

```
<activity android:name="path.to.the.activity.MyMainActivity">

     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Now you finally have an entry point to your Android application and you can begin creating `ReportCard` objects and start messing around with them:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.my_empty_layout);

         ReportCard myFirstReportCard = new ReportCard("SO College", "Mr. Kooijman", "2016", "aylin", 80, 72, 55);
         int socialStudiesGrade = myFirstReportCard.getSocialStudiesGrade();
    }
}
```

However, I do strongly suggest that you read up some more on what an Android application is and how one should go about creating one. The question you've posed indicates a great lack of understandning about what the platform is, how and what it enables you do to and how you should be doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.android.reportcard.ReportCard> has no zero argument constructor
```

If you don't define some custom constructor - java creates one for you (defaul with no parameters)
But if you do - then you should define every required manualy.

Comment: Hello, i saw it before but when i was add "no zero argument constructor" i
receive error

Answer (score 0):

I also had an error statement that said "has no zero argument constructor".  What was happening was the program was attempting to start the program from my DatabaseOpenHelper class instead of starting in the main class.  It was doing this because I created the DatabaseOpenHelper class first, then created the MainActivity class.
The solution took a while to find, but turned out to be fairly simple.  I had to go into the manifest file and find the line including "DatabaseOpenHelper" where it was telling the program to start there, then change it from "DatabaseOpenHelper" to "MainActivity".